# Caption's space of Figure with subfigure

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

I can not alignment vertical space. There is too much gap. I want to use the \vspace{-1ex} code, but I could not.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2c.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1.6b}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2d.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1.6c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(a), (b) [\cite{13}]}\label{fig:1.6}
\end{figure}
```

https://ibb.co/w0r12qt

Comment: you could use --    `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}` to reduce space -- or-- use `\usepackage[labelformat=empty,skip=1em]{subcaption}`
to remove the `subcaptions` and have only on main `caption` at the desired spacing of `1em` -- please see the answer below

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2c.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:1.6b}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
        %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2d.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:1.6c}
        \end{subfigure}
            \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
        \caption{(a), (b) [\cite{13}]}\label{fig:1.6}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

OR --you could try the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty,skip=1em]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2c.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:1.6b}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
        %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/Chapter I/Added/2d.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:1.6c}
        \end{subfigure}
                \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
        \caption{(a), (b) [\cite{13}]}\label{fig:1.6}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]